# query confusing submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

I'm very new to jQuery and having some trouble. My project has a login/register page using forms, and is restricted to using localStorage. When I run the project, it's as if the submit buttons for sign-in and sign-up are being confused, although they have different id tags. I am very confused, I know the problem is probably very stupid, but I have been searching for a few hours and can't fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="welcome.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
<h1>My Calendar</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-corner-all">Sign-in</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">

  <form method="post" action=" ">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="fullname">Full name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">       

    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email..">
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
  </div>


  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<a href="#myPopup1" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-corner-all">Sign-up</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup1" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">

  <form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action=" ">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="fullname">Full name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class = "stored">       

    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email.." class = "stored">
  </div>
  <input id= "submitcheck" type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (localStorage["name"]&&localStorage["email"]) {
        window.location.href = "calendar.html";}
     else {$("<div>Incorrect Entry</div>").dialog();}



$('#localStorageTest').submitcheck(function() {
$('.stored').keyup(function () {
localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();}
}); });
</script>
```

Comment: *"buttons getting confused"* isn't a proper technical problem statement that tells us anything of value. Also no idea what `submitcheck()` is since it is not a jQuery core method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, looking at your code (I made a fiddle here, with your code https://jsfiddle.net/webbm/edfwoxxh/), you're trying to do some kind of check of the input of the form with id `localStorageTest`

If you change your code to use this, it will hit the correct function when you submit on Sign Up only:

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
  /* Your code here */ 
});
```

You'll need to do something other than  `$('.stored').keyup` in there, because that doesn't really make sense. If you want to check the values of your input you could do something like this:

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
  var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  if(fullname) {
    //fullname has a value
  }
});
```